# Button in every WPF DataGrid Column

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, datagrid

I want to add an button to every wpf datagrid column. my columns are generated automatically so i dont have the definitions of the columns in the xaml. how can i do this with a template for the columns, so that i have my column header and on the right a button.

EDIT:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding User.myDataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Here I want my ColumnName" />
                                <Button Content="Button"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

The User.myDataTable is filled in the Model and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can this this by using a style:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColumnName}" />
                            <Button Content="Button" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
         </Style>
     </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
 <DataGrid>
```

Comment: ok that works well, but how can i do the binding to my columnname? they are created automatically and the source of my datagrid is binded to a datatable in my model

Comment: Try this: <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />

Comment: And you might need to change your binding from "User.myDataTable" to "User.myDataTable.DefaultView"

Comment: Just a note, I don't normally bind to DataTables, so I'm not to familiar with that approach.

Comment: ok that works, but now my DataGrid shows one column with textbox text: Application.ViewModels.UserViewmodel and then the button. And if the datagridd is filled that text is overflow by the columns that generated automatically. do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 use the below code:-

    DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();

    FrameworkElementFactory HeaderStackpanel = new    FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
    FrameworkElementFactory btn = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
    // Set the property for  Button

    btn.SetValue(Button.MarginProperty, new Thickness(-50, 0, 0, 0));
    btn.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(BtnClick));
     // Set the Text Value to the buttons

    btn.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, strEdit);

   // Append the Edit Button

   HeaderStackpanel.AppendChild(btn);
   DataTemplate headerTemplate = new DataTemplate();
   headerTemplate.VisualTree = HeaderStackpanel;

   templateColumn.HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate;
```